# PHP Intelephense not showing 'Import' option

Tags: visual-studio-code, laravel-8, intelephense

I just instlled PHP Intelephense extension in Visual Studio code. When I hover over a class and right click, it will not show import in the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Php Namespace Resolver by Mehedi Hassan for Import and Expand php namespaces

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin has the very significant drawback that it neither allows extra include paths (it relies on folders inside the workspace) nor uses those of Intelephense.